# What is the main idea of 7.Qf3 in the Sicilian Taimanov?

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense, sicilian-taimanov

In the Sicilian Taimanov, after the opening moves

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "12"]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 e6 5.Nc3 Qc7 6.Be3 a6
```

7.Qf3 has become popular recently. I find it still a bit strange move however...What is (or are) the main ideas and perhaps tactical themes behind this move?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main ideas:

1. Castling long as soon as possible
2. The Qf3 will most often move to g3 to pressure g7 and d6, and possibly help the break e4-e5.
3. Both central files are left for the rooks to apply maximum pressure (unlike after Qd2 or Qe2 developments)